# Remove writable attribute warning - Reek

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reek

The model is defined as follows

```
attr_accessor :delay_type, :stop_type
```

This raises the following warning by reek

> Order#stop_type is a writable attribute

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You're making of both `delay_type` and `stop_type` a writable and readable attribute, which might not be needed if you're only using them to get their values, not to reassign them. If so, changing `attr_accessor` for `attr_reader` should remove the warning.

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor` creates both `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`.

You have created both but you are not using the writer so reek is raising a warning that you have extra code that is not being used.

You should either ignore the warning if you will use the writer later or do this:

```
attr_accessor :delay_type
attr_reader :stop_type
```